# Using mySQL joins to select like information

Tags: mysql, sql

Was a hard title to write, I fear it didn't explain much!

Basically I have a table, let's call it Links

Links consists of these columns (and I'll add test data,  seperated for viewing):

```
linksid | folderid | link
   1            1        www.example.com
   2            1        www.anotherexample.com

   3            2        www.example.com
   4            2        www.anotherexample.com
   5            2        www.auniquewebsite.com
```

Now what I want to do is when get the unique website from folderid 2, because of that folder having 2 links that also exist in folderid 1 - I want to create a suggestion for a user.

So far I have:

```
  SELECT b.folderid, b.link FROM Links b

  LEFT OUTER JOIN Links a 

  ON  a.link = b.link AND  a.folderid <> b.folderid

  WHERE (a.folderid = 1)
```

However this query only brings up these results, as there's no selector to do anything with the like matches:

```
linksid | folderid | link
   1            1        www.example.com
   2            1        www.anotherexample.com

   3            2        www.example.com
   4            2        www.anotherexample.com
```

I've been trying some other selectors(like and a.link IS null) but they all just bring up no results. Ideally I'd want to get the unique link and that only when atleast 2 links in the same folder match the searched-from folder

I feel like I'm approaching this from the wrong angle, anyone have any tips to push me in the right direction?

Comment: You've said what you currently get but not what you actually want. Can you add an example of what you would like the output to be?

Comment: Oh, my mistake.



In this example I'd want the output to be
  folderid = 2, linkid = 5, link = www.auniquewebsite.com

I'd want the query to select this output because folderid 2 has 2 matching links with folderid 1, so folderid 1 would most likely be interested in acquiring the link from folderid 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the row for folder = 2 that doesn't exist for folder = 1.  Here is one approach using `left outer join`:

```
select l2.*
from Links l2 left outer join
     Links l1
     on l2.link = l1.link and
        l1.folder = 1
where l2.folder = 2 and l1.link is null;
```

EDIT:

If you want all the "unmatched" links for folders that match all links to folder 1, then the query is more complicated.  The following gets the folders that contain all the links for l1, and then perhaps some more:

```
select l2.folder
from links l1 left outer join
     links l2
     on l1.link = l2.link
where l1.folder = 1
group by l2.folder
having sum(l2.link is null) = 0;
```

To get all the links for these that are not in folder 1, use subqueries and more logic:

```
select l.*
from (select l2.folder
      from links l1 left outer join
           links l2
           on l1.link = l2.link
      where l1.folder = 1
      group by l2.folder
      having sum(l2.link is null) = 0
     ) l2 join
     links l
     on l2.folder = l.folder
where not exists (select 1
                  from links l1
                  where l1.folder = 1 and
                        l1.link = l.link
                 );
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want, however I need that row without knowing that folderid = 2 is the folder with the matching row. I need to first find the folderid that has 2 matching links with folderid 1.

Comment: That edit solves my problem perfectly, thank you.

Going to study the query to figure out why now though. :p

Thanks again

Comment: @user3548528 . . . It is an interesting problem and rather unique.  I do wonder if there is a simpler method, but I'm glad the above works.